# Update Opportunity with Force.com Site From

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I don't know why, but my force.com site is not updating my opportunity when I go to it and try and update a "survey" we send.

The data populates on the page correctly just doesn't get sent to the opportunity on submission.

Here's the controller I am using:

```
public class OpptyCont {
public Opportunity opportunity{ get
        {
        opportunity = [SELECT Id, Name ,X1__c,X2__c,X3__c,X4__c,X5__c,X6__c,X7__c,X8__c,X9__c FROM Opportunity
                WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];
        return opportunity;
        }
             set;
    } 

    public OpptyCont() {
    }


     public PageReference save() {
     try{
           update opportunity;
        }catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here's the Apex Page:

```
     <apex:page Controller="OpptyCont" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

       <apex:pageBlock title="Survey Questions for {!Opportunity.Name}">
      <b>Please fill out the following Questions:</b>
       </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:form >
    <br></br>
    <b>1.</b><apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.X1__c}"/>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <apex:inputTextarea label="{!Opportunity.X1__c}" value="{!Opportunity.X1__c}" id="X1__c" style="width:80%" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
   <b> 2.</b><apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.X2__c}"/><br></br>
    <apex:inputTextarea label="{!Opportunity.X2__c}" value="{!Opportunity.X2__c}"    id="X2__c" style="width:80%" />
   <br></br>
   <br></br>
    <b>3.</b><apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.X3__c}"/><br></br>
    <apex:inputTextarea label="{!Opportunity.X3__c}" value="{!Opportunity.X3__c}" id="X3__c" style="width:80%" />
   <br></br>
   <br></br>
    <b>4.</b><apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.X4__c}"/><br></br>
    <apex:inputTextarea label="{!Opportunity.X4__c}" value="{!Opportunity.X4__c}"    id="X4__c" style="width:80%" />
   <br></br>
   <br></br>
    <b>5.</b><apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.X5__c}"/><br></br>
    <apex:inputTextarea label="{!Opportunity.X5__c}" value="{!Opportunity.X5__c}" id="X5__c" style="width:80%" />
   <br></br>
   <br></br>
    <b>6.</b><apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.X6__c}"/><br></br>
    <apex:inputTextarea label="{!Opportunity.X6__c}" value="{!Opportunity.X6__c}" id="X6__c" style="width:80%" />
   <br></br>
   <br></br>
    <b>7.</b><apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.X7__c}"/><br></br>
    <apex:inputTextarea label="{!Opportunity.X7__c}" value="{!Opportunity.X7__c}" id="X7__c" style="width:80%" />
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
     <b>8.</b><apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.X8__c}"/><br></br>
     <apex:inputTextarea label="{!Opportunity.X8__c}" id="X8__c" style="width:80%" />

    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" />
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

If you can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SF does not allow you to edit or update records on standard objects(Account, Opportunity, Lead, Etc). You need to create a custom object that will hold the data and create a trigger that will update the data on your standard object.

You can only insert a new record on a standard object.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Site's Profile (it's available under one of the buttons in the site configuration). Maybe the "guest user" doesn't have rights to update Opportunities?

Check if anything changes if the you modify class definition to `public without sharing class OpptyCont` - maybe he doesn't have rights to edit this particular record?

Last but not least - in the Setup -> Monitoring -> Debug Logs you can put your site name in the box (it should find something similar to "MySiteName Guest user"), this should help tracking what's going on.

Comment: Eyescream- Thanks for the feedback. It turns out it was just a permissions issue. Salesforce doesn't allow you to edit standard objects via Sites only custom objects. So created a separate object that has a trigger that updates the opportunity.

Comment: Weird, my Site has a "contact us" form that ends up as a standard Case record in SF (insert, not update though)... Can you please post it as an answer & accept it so it's easier to find for people with similar problem?